# How can I reuse the terraform output values in another deployment

Tags: azure, terraform

I have a terraform code that deploys Azure resources and outputs a bunch of values I need to use for further configuration.

I have initialized terraform backend and the state is saved to an Azure Storage account, I see the tfstate file with all the correct values.

FYI I have added this configuration but still no luck, also I am running the terraform init command in the second location so the backend is initialized with the same state:

```
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name  = "${var.STATE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}"
    container_name        = "${var.STATE_CONTAINER_NAME}"
    key                   = "${var.STATE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY}"
  }
```

What I want to be able to do is pull this state in some way so I can do terraform output -raw some_output in a different location than where I deployed the resources.

I can't seem to find a way to do this. How could this be achieved? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a straight forward way to do this, so the solution was, since the state file was being saved to Azure Blob Storage:

1. Run an Azure CLI command to get the blob locally:

   ```
   az storage blob download --container-name tstate --file $tf_state_file_name --name $tf_state_file_name --account-key $tf_state_key --account-name $tf_state_storage_account_name
   ```

   Where the local file name is: `$tf_state_file_name`
2. Read the desired values using JQ:

   ```
   jq '.outputs.storage_account_name.value' ./$tf_state_file_name -r
   ```

   You can read the values raw thanks to the `-r` paramater. This is the same as doing:

   ```
   terraform output -raw storage_account_name
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your use case. You can take two different approaches:

### Import resource with "data" source

> Data sources allow Terraform use information defined outside of Terraform, defined by another separate Terraform configuration, or modified by functions.
> [Terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html)

For AWS it would be something like this:

```
// create ssm parameter in Terraform code A
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "secret" {
  name  = "/secret"
  type  = "String"
  value = "SecretValue"
}

// Import this resource in Terraform code B
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "imported_secret" {
  name = "/secret"
}

// So later you can reference it
locals any {
  secretValue = data.aws_ssm_parameter.secret.value
}
```

### Create modules

> Modules are containers for multiple resources that are used together. A module consists of a collection of .tf and/or .tf.json files kept together in a directory. Modules are the main way to package and reuse resource configurations with Terraform.
> [Terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/index.html)

It is basic example of Terraform modules. We created module `vpc` where source of this module is in `../../modules/vpc` directory and we referenced this module by `module.vpc` in `rds` module.

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "../../modules/vpc"

  env = var.env
  azs = var.azs

  cidr = var.cidr

  db_subnets = var.db_subnets
  private_subnets = var.private_subnets
  public_subnets = var.public_subnets
}


module "rds" {
  source = "../../modules/rds"

  db_subnets_cidr_blocks = module.vpc.db_subnets_cidr_block
  private_subnets_cidr_blocks = module.vpc.private_subnets_cidr_block
  public_subnets_cidr_blocks = module.vpc.public_subnets_cidr_block

  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

  env = var.env

  db_subnets_ids = module.vpc.db_subnets
}
```